# DataTable Primefaces Propiedad copiar celdas

Tags: primefaces

¿Existe alguna propiedad que me permita arrastrar una celda de una tabla en primefaces y se vaya copiando?

El comportamiento sería como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Nachfren. Has investigado e intentado algo ?  Qué errores o problemas has encontrado ?  Mira [ask] y [help/on-topic] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Pues he buscado en la documetacion, pero no he visto nada asi

Comment: @nachfren yo no he visto que se pueda hacer algo así lo que podría hacerse tal vez es editar la celda pero tendrías que escribir el nombre